# ltrim strips more than needed

Tags: php

Is there a way to limit exactly what ltrim removes in PHP.

I had a the following outcome:

```
$str = "axxMyString";
$newStr = ltrim($str, "ax");
// result MyString and it should have been xMyString
```

Comment: ltrim removes all instances of the characters in the given string, not instances of the string itself (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 4):

If you know that the first two characters should be stripped, use:

```
$str = substr($str, 2);
```

`ltrim($str, $chars)` removes every occurence from `$chars` from the **l**eft side of the string.

If you only want to strip the first two characters when these equals `ax`, you would use:

```
if (substr($str, 0, 2) == 'ax') $str = substr($str, 2);
```

- Manual page on [ltrim()](http://php.net/ltrim)
- Manual page on [substr()](http://php.net/substr)

Comment: cool, this will work for now! Thanks. Still I am puzzled with the ltrim behavior...

Comment: From the [description of ltrim](http://php.net/ltrim): "Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning of a string.". `ltrim()` removes all occurences of characters from the second parameter on the left side. It's not removing a substring.

Answer (score 1):

[ltrim()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) manual:

> Strip whitespace (or other characters)
>   from the beginning of a string.

So...

```
$newStr = ltrim($str, "ax");
```

This will remove every character `'a'` and `'x'` at the beginning of string `$str`.

Use [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) to get part of string you need.

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter species each character that will be trimmed. Because you defined both `a` and `x` the first the letters got removed from your string.

Just do:

```
$newStr = ltrim($str, "a");
```

and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regexp too:

```
$string = preg_replace('#^ax#', '', $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the confusion has come in because ltrim receives a list of characters to remove, not a string. Your code removes all occurrences of `a` *or* `x` not the string `ax`. So `axxxaxxaMyString` becomes `MyString` and `axxaiaxxaMyString` becomes `iaxxaMyString`.

If you know how many characters you need to remove, you can use `substr()` otherwise for more complicated patterns, you can use regular expressions via `preg_replace()`.