# Why does ltrim remove one character when the second argument contains an operator sign?

Tags: php, string, trim

If I do:

```
ltrim('53-34567', '53-');
ltrim('53+34567', '53+');
ltrim('53*34567', '53*');
```

I get `4567` as the result and not `34567`. What's the explanation for this behavior?

Comment: The ltrim() function removes whitespace or other predefined characters from the left side of a string. [Link](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_ltrim.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ltrim strips more than needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5654852/ltrim-strips-more-than-needed), or [PHP ltrim behavior with character list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9050917/php-ltrim-behavior-with-character-list)

Comment: The second parameter is a _set_ of characters, not a _sequence_ of characters.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
ltrim('53-34567', '53-');
```

There is a `5` at the begining of `'53-34567'` so it is removed.

There is a `3` at the begining of `'3-34567'` so it is removed.

There is a `-` at the begining of `'-34567'` so it is removed.

There is a `3` at the begining of `'34567'` so it is removed.

There is nothing in `'53-'` at the begining of `'4567'` so it stopped.

This is the same behaviour than a `trim()` by removing unwanted **trailing** characters. In example, `trim("   lots    of   spaces   ");` will return `"lots    of   spaces"` by removing **trailing** and **leading** spaces but will keep the inner ones.

Comment: Very clear! Thank you!

Comment: This is a very clear and good explanation of what is happening. Far more useful than throwing around the `character_mask` definition. If I may suggest something, add "Continue removing `5` or `3` or `-` from the left side of `53-34567`." somewhere in your answer.

Answer (score 17):

The second argument of `ltrim()` is as follows

> **character_mask**
>   You can also specify the characters you want to strip, by means of the character_mask parameter. Simply list all characters that you want to be stripped.

It's used to specify which characters to trim, yours include `3`. If you know what you want to extract, you can use other string functions.

As to why the other `5` is then not removed, see this comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php#118221

Comment: I don't think I understand :)  In this case, why doesn't `5` get trimmed also? The end result contains `5`. Also, if I use `53` as the second argument (without any operator sign), I get the `+34567` result.

Comment: @sica07 : try `ltrim('52*34567', '52*');` you will get your answer

Comment: To be more precise, trim() excludes the characters listed in the second parameter (independently of how often they occur) and not the argument string. In the OT's example the three lines could be reduced to `ltrim($str, '+3-5*')` (or any other permutation of the characters) and work the same.

Answer (score 6):

This is because `ltrim` trims characters from a second param.

How it works:

1. start read a string(first param) from left.
2. check if first-left char is in a list of 'character-to-trim' list.
3. If 2 is YES - trim it and go to step 1.
4. if 2 is NO - exit.