# Removing three dots after or before a newline

Tags: php, regex

I use this function to remove three dots before or after a newline:

```
private function trimThreeDots(string $text): string {
    $threeDotsAtTheBeginning = '((^|[\n]{1})[\\.]{3})';
    $threeDotsAtTheEnd = '([\\.]{3}[\n]{1})';

    $pattern = '/' . $threeDotsAtTheBeginning . '|' . $threeDotsAtTheEnd . '/';

    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, function ($str) {
        return str_replace("...", "", $str[0]);
    }, $text);
}
```

It works, except that in case that I have a string like this one:

```
"Bla bla bla...
...bla bla bla"
```

I only get a single match. But I want to get two matches, because I need to remove both occurrences of three dots. I wonder if maybe there is a more straightforward and efficient way to write this regex and getting two matches in the above case?

Comment: You don't need regex, just put the newline character in your `str_replace()` source string.

Comment: Without regex I would consider splitting into lines, `trim()` the dots, and re-join if necessary.

Comment: @AndyG `trim()` won't do the job. The second argument is a list of characters to trim. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50174181/why-does-ltrim-remove-one-character-when-the-second-argument-contains-an-operato/50174338#50174338)

Comment: The list could just contain a single character, a dot.

Comment: This will remove any number of leading/trailing dots. Try this `echo trim("bla bla bla.......", '.');`

Comment: @Cid Yes, I was assuming just a sequence of dots, not stressing the need to remove explicitly three of them. But I'm not necessarily trying to present an alternative solution, just a comment that regex might be overkill for such a task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may use

```
$s = "Bla bla bla...
...bla bla bla";
echo preg_replace('~(?:\.{3})?(\R)(?:\.{3})?~', '$1', $s);
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/2ACpTC) and a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/RtsvL5/3).

**Details**

- `(?:\.{3})?` - an optional sequence of 3 dots
- `(\R)` - Group 1: any line break sequence
- `(?:\.{3})?` - an optional sequence of 3 dots

The `$1` replacement replaces the match with the exact line break sequence the regex matches.

Comment: Didn't need the "\h*" because I am not removing the three dots in case that there is a space after or before a newline. But the rest is ok, thanks.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri Then why use `\s*` in your `'([\\.]{3}[\s]*[\n]{1})'` pattern? Ok, since that was your pattern error, I removed the `\h*` part.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the RegEx [`\.{3}(?=\n)|(?<=\n)\.{3}`](https://regex101.com/r/iNqq27/1)

- `\.{3}(?=\n)` matches the case where the newline is after the dots
- `(?<=\n)\.{3}` matches the case where the newline is before the dots

[**Demo.**](https://regex101.com/r/iNqq27/1)

---

**[PHP:](https://ideone.com/GIURNg)**

```
preg_replace('~\.{3}(?=\n)|(?<=\n)\.{3}~', '', $s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems overly complex maybe?
What about this?

```
$re = '/(^\.{3}|\.{3}$)/gm';
$str = 'Bla bla bla...
...bla bla bla';
$subst = '';

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);

echo "The result of the substitution is ".$result;
```